# Fetch defect from rally using rally rest api v2.0

Tags: rally

I am getting the following exception whenever i try to fetch defects from rally:

```
            com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
            com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use  JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12
            at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
            at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
            at com.rallydev.rest.response.Response.<init>(Response.java:25)
            at com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse.<init>(QueryResponse.java:16)
            at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.query(RallyRestApi.java:168)
            at Test.main(Test.java:86)
            Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1386)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:531)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414)
            at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:60)
            ... 5
```

What intrigues me most is the code works perfectly fine on few machines and throws the  above exception on few.

code snippet :

```
RallyRestApi restApi = 
new RallyRestApi(new URI("http://rally1.rallydev.com"),apiKey);
QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest("defects");
queryRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Project","FormattedID","Release"));
QueryFilter filter1 = new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", defetctID);
QueryResponse queryResponse1 =  restApi.query(queryRequest);
```

Comment: Please format your code properly so that it is easily readable.

Comment: i have edited the code snippet . please check it once

Answer (score 0):

Try a curl command to read the same defect using the same apiKey (in zsessionid header) on the same machine from which your java code fails.

```
curl --header "ZSESSIONID: _abc123" "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/123456789"
```

At least you will know if this is specific to java or not. Yes, it is strange that it fails on some machines and works on others, but the timing of those tests is not obvious from your post, and I wonder if this has anything to do with the underlying user credentials. (A user gets disabled for a period of time after a number of unsuccessful attempts). I am not positive that this is the issue you experience but I have seen  when expired password caused the exact same error. API Keys are tied to a user, so when a user's password is expired, or when a user is inactivated (disabled) the same permissions(or the lack of them) is reflected in the key. For example, a user did not know that the password was expired because in the Rally UI they used SSO authentiation, but in the code they used either username/password or APIKey since the toolkit does not support SSO at this point. A 401 error would be more helpful, but instead a malformed JSON is generated.